# Can I force remove mods in minecraft forge?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-forge

I want to remove some mods after I played and build some mod's stuffs (like pipe in buildcraft). If I just delete mod, minecraft launcher will get error at start (It say something like missing block ids or can't map block ids or something like this.). Is there any way to just remove it or replace mod's stuffs with something like sand when remove mods.

edit: I forgot to mention that I want to fix it on my server not single player game.

ps: Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove a mod and load a world that used parts of it it should pop up a message saying Ids are missing and bad things might happen and the like. But you should be able to continue on and actually load the world... All the blocks that no longer are understood are instead changed into air blocks.. I have had a few interesting results doing this not on purpose at times.

Comment: It's work if I play on single player, but how about on server (like on MCPC+).

Comment: It should behave in the same way, except it will not ask you to continue it will just load the world and turn things it does not understand to air blocks.

Answer (score 0):

When testing a map that had used forge mods after trying to make it vanilla and turning it into a server, if it's online and you use forge that still has the mods on it, even after it should have replaced it with air blocks, there are all sorts of errors. Remnants of blocks added that only you can see if you still have the mods